# Why does my angularJS controller doesnt work?

Tags: angularjs

Today I decided to try out some tricks of AngularJS! Can someone explain me what is the problem with my code? This example was shown in video I downloaded to learn Angular. When I try it, it shows me an error tip:

```html
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function Test($scope){
   $scope.persons =
   [{name: 'Me', city:'Saint Pete'}, {name: 'Other', city:'Moscow'}]};
 </script>
<title>
 ANGULAR
</title>

</head>

<body>
 <div data-ng-controller="Test">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
  <ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: name"> {{person.name}} - {{person.city}} </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error tip in the console:
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=Test&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Nb (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:19:417)
    at ob (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:20:1)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:75:177
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:57:112
    at r (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at I (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:56:496)
    at g (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/angular/angular.min.js:51:316)

Comment: [Read this commit message](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018).

Answer (score 1):

The ng-app tag should have a name, and your test definition should be as follow: 
`ng-app="mayApp"`
`angular.module ("myapp",[]) //definition of the angular module` 
your test should be defined as a controller as follow: 

      `angular.module ("myapp").controller ("Test", function Test (){`
           `//test function should go here.` 
      `});`

Answer (score 0):

You have not added AngulaJS in your page. Just add the below line in head section.

```
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You could also download angularjs file and give its path.